# Cramer-Rao bound for LS estimator

Tags: statistics

It's a problem from *Machine Learning: A Bayesian And Optimization Perspective* (problem 3.7):
Derive the Cramer-Rao bound for the LS estimator, when the training data result from the linear model $$y_n=\theta x_n+\eta_n, n=1, 2, ..., N$$ where $x_n$ and $\eta_n$ are i.i.d sample of a zero mean random variable, with variance of $\sigma^2_x$ and a Gaussian one with zero mean and variance of $\sigma^2_{\eta}$, respectively. Assume, also, that x and η are independent. Then show that the LS estimator $$\theta=\frac{\sum^N_{n=1}{x_n y_n}}{\sum^N_{n=1}{x_n^2}}$$ achieves the CR bound only asymptotically.

It needs the pdf of $y_n$ which is the sum of two independent random variables, am I supposed to use the convolution formula (the theorem of summation of two random variables)? It seems the calculation would go extremely difficult because of the integration：$$\text{y}\sim\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\frac{1}{\theta}p(\frac{y}{\theta})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_{\eta}^2}}\text{exp}(-\frac{(y-u)^2}{2\sigma_{\eta^2}})\text{du}}, \text{where}\,\,p\,\,\text{is the pdf of x}$$ there is a $\theta$ in $p$ which mostly causes the computational difficulty.

Any helps or hints will be appriciated.

Comment: From the question it is not clear to me if the $x_n$'s are Gaussian. Are they?

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, and I have to set a $p$ in the density term.

Comment: @StubbornAtom sadly it's not, I 've seen the same question in this web with a gaussian version answer.

Comment: Follow the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Included computation of the cramer-Rao-bound

Note that $Y|X \sim  \mathcal{N}(\theta X;\sigma_\eta^2)$

We have that $I_{(X,Y)}(\theta)  = I_{Y|X}(\theta) = \mathbb{E}_{\theta,x} [ \frac{\partial \ln p(y|x)}{\partial \theta}^2] = \mathbb{E}_{\theta,x}[\frac{X^2}{\sigma_\eta^2}] = \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_\eta^2} $

By the ["chain rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) for fisher information.

Also, for the asymptotics you will not need to evaluate the density if you do it in the following way:

First, separate the terms:

$\frac{\sum_n x_n y_n}{\sum_n x_n^2} = \theta \frac{\sum_n x_n^2}{\sum_n x_n^2} + \frac{\sum_n x_n \eta_n}{\sum_n x_n^2} = \theta + \frac{\sum_n x_n \eta_n}{\sum_n x_n^2} $

Now check the asymptotics:

$ \sqrt{n}(\theta + \frac{\sum_n x_n \eta_n}{\sum_n x_n^2} - \theta) = \sqrt{n} ( \frac{\sum_n x_n \eta_n}{\sum_n x_n^2}) = \sqrt{n} ( \frac{\frac{\sum_n x_n \eta_n}{n}}{\frac{\sum_n x_n^2}{n}})  = \sqrt{n} \frac{\overline{X \eta}}{\overline{X^2}}$

Now, by the law of large numbers, 
$ \overline{X^2} \overset{P}{\rightarrow} \sigma_x^2 $

And, by the central limit theorem (and the independence of $X$,$\eta$):
$\sqrt{n} \overline{X \eta} \overset{D}{\rightarrow}  \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_x^2 \sigma_\eta^2)$

Hence, by the Slutsky theorem/continuos mapping theorem, you get that:

$ \sqrt{n} \frac{\overline{X \eta}}{\overline{X^2}} \overset{D}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{\sigma_\eta^2}{\sigma_x^2})$

which is the inverse of the Fisher information, as required.

Comment: Thanks for your work, but I'm sorry I can't  figure out how it helps. Would you please give more details? And I think you didn't calculate the CR bound.

Comment: I included some details on how to get the Cramer-Rao bound, so with the asymptotics you can see that the estimator asymptotically attains it. Now for the finite sample setting, try some similar conditioning trick (using conditional variance). Also note that for these computations we do not need that $X$ is a gaussian, only $\eta$.

Comment: Your answer looks fine. But check the formula of $I_{Y\mid X}(\theta)$ for typos and consider removing 'continuous mapping theorem' towards the end (Slutsky's theorem is enough).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out typos. In the end, slutskys theorem is just a particular application of continuos mapping theorem, thats why I put it like this...

Comment: Thanks for your patience and work, I made a summary as another answer and gave yours a vote and accept!

Answer (score 0):

This is partly a summary, and thanks to works by @a_student, @StubbornAtom, and @jld in https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/320600. This may be the final answer to this problem, please point out mistakes if you find some.

First, we compute the C-R bound of the estimator, by the definition of 
$$
I_{(X, Y)}(\theta)=-\mathbb{E}_{\left( X,Y \right)}\text{[}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \theta ^2}\ln p\left( X,Y;\theta \right) \text{]}, \text{where}\,\,X=\left( x_1,x_2,...,x_N \right) ^T, Y=\left( y_1,y_2,...,y_N \right) ^T
$$
and the chain rule, we have that
$$
I_{\left( X,Y \right)}\left( \theta \right) 
=-\mathbb{E}_{(X, Y)}\left[ \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \theta ^2}\ln p\left( Y|X;\theta \right) \right] +0
$$
as $X$'s distribution doesn't consists of $\theta$, and we have $Y|X\sim \mathcal{N}\left( \theta X, \sigma _{\eta}^{2}I \right) $, after computation we get
$$
C-R\,\,bound=\frac{1}{I\left( \theta \right)}=\frac{\sigma _{\eta}^{2}}{N\sigma _{x}^{2}}
$$

Then, compute the variance of the estimator $\hat{\theta}$. By the computation in @jld 's work we have 
$$
Var(\hat{\theta})=σ^2_\eta\,\mathbb{E}_X[\frac{1}{X^TX}]
$$
we don't have a Gaussion X, but it suffices to prove that $\mathbb{E}_X[\frac{1}{X^TX}]\rightarrow 0$, as $N\rightarrow\infty$. 
By the law of large numbers, $\overline{X^T X}\xrightarrow{P}\sigma^2_x$, then by continuous mapping theorem we have
$$
\frac{1}{X^TX}=\frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{\overline{X^TX}}\xrightarrow{P}0
$$
we finally get the result that $\hat{\theta}$ asymptotically attains the bound, since both of them tends to 0 as $N\rightarrow\infty$.